# RXJava : wait until other observable has completed

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I am relatively new to RX world. So, there are many operators which I don't understand. I have spent a few hours to figure out the solution for my problem.

Which is:

I have one 'cold' observable(**observable I**) which emits only one result. It is for loading some initial data before application could load other items to show

On the other side, I have another 'hot' observable(**observable II**) which is loading data with paging, therefore emitting many results.

I want **observable II** to wait for **observable I**. If at the moment the **observable II** is created, **observable I** has already finished, I want **observable II** to not load initial data again.

To visualise :

```
  Case 1

  Observable I  [---------------------------------------------------]

  Observable II  .................[----------------------------------------
```

Here **observabele II** should wait for **observable I** and only continue to work after that.

```
  Case 2 

  Observable I   [--------]

  Observable II ...............[----------------------------------------
```

Here **observable II** should only check that **observable I** is finished and continue working

In both cases, execution of **observable I** should not happen more than once.

**Question:**

How can I do this using RX combining operators?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use either [`concat`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#concat-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-) or [`concatWith`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#concatWith-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-) here. The operators do the same, it's just static vs non-static methods.

Let's say you got `result = obs1.concatWith(obs2)`; what this operator does is:

1. it subscribes to `obs1` and emits all elements it receives from its `onNext`.
2. once `obs1` calls `onCompleted`, it unsubscribes from `obs1` and subscribes to `obs2`. It will likewise emit all elements it receives from `obs2`'s `onNext`.
3. once `obs2` calls `onCompleted`, it calls `onCompleted` as well, since no more elements will come from either `Observable`.

Comment: your answer really gave me a direction but concat didn't work,
I posted corrected question https://stackoverflow.com/q/48398348/3904645