# RxJava: Combining hot and cold observable to wait for each other

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin, rx-kotlin2

I have my observables defined like this

```
    val initLoading = Observable.fromCallable { println("${System.currentTimeMillis()}") }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .delay(WAIT_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .map { "loading ${System.currentTimeMillis()}" }
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

    val click = RxView.clicks(button).map { "click ${System.currentTimeMillis()}" }
    initLoading.concatWith(click)
            .subscribeBy(
                    onNext = { println("result $it") },
                    onError = { throw it }
            )
```

`initialLoading` starts running at Activity's `onCreate` method. `click` is executed on button click. I have two cases and first is working, second isn't.

**case 1**

activity starts and button is clicked **after** `WAIT_TIME` seconds. Output:

```
   01-23 13:08:07.170  I/System.out: 1516698487170
   01-23 13:08:17.174  I/System.out: result loading 1516698497172
   01-23 13:08:29.258  I/System.out: result click 1516698509258
```

**case 2**

activity starts and button is clicked **before** `WAIT_TIME` period is over. Output

```
   01-23 13:09:07.392 I/System.out: 1516698547392
   01-23 13:09:17.398 I/System.out: result loading 1516698557395
```

so, the problem is that the click event is lost. I want the click event to wait for the loading, and then continue working. in short, case 2 output should be the same as case 1.

How can i chive this using rx operators. I tried `merge` but it just combines both and click event doesn't wait for loading.

I also tried `reply, cache, publish, share` but couldn't get the right combination of them to work as I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `concatWith` operator is good for your use case but the second observable should start to store click events immediately after it is created so that the stored events can be emitted when the observable is subscribed to (which happens when `initLoading` completes). This can be achieved by modifying your `click` observable with `replay()` and `connect()`.

```
val replayedClicks = click.replay();
replayedClicks.connect(); // The original click observable is subscribed to at this point
```

Now you can use `replayedClicks` in the `concatWith`, and its stored events will be replayed after `initLoading` finishes:

```
initLoading.concatWith(replayedClicks)
        .subscribeBy(
                onNext = { println("result $it") },
                onError = { throw it }
        )
```

Comment: really nice combination and solution as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try combineLatest instead of concatWith. "result loading" would be always the same though